# Unity doesn't hide in VirtualBox Fullscreen Mode

Tags: 14.04, unity, virtualbox, fullscreen

I am running Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04. 
Everything works perfectly except the fullscreen mode. Windows expands to the fullscreen resolution, but Unity's Launcher and top panel always shows on top and overlaps the top and the left edge of Windows.

Every other application works just fine in fullscreen mode (VLC, Youtube in Chrome, etc..)

I searched across the web but couldn't find a solution.

Here is a picture of my problem.
[Unity overlapping VirtualBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64nq793f1medcjg/virtualbox.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Vbox 4.3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04 with W7 guest. Unckecking **Mini ToolBar** fixed it (machine settings -> General -> Advanced).

[image]

Regards,
Greg

Comment: It's the real solution, regardless of the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution for you: downgrading to version `4.3.10`!
I assume you downloaded the latest version from virtualbox.org and had this issue. Well I did as well. So I uninstalled it and installed the slightly outdated version from the software center using

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.3
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

(or use software center if you'd like)
the version is `4.3.10` as opposed to `4.3.16` and the extension pack isn't listed on the main page of the sight it list like `4.3.16` and then `4.2.x.x` those will not work. The appropriate package can be found here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3
You want version 4.3.10!